# Gerrit code review

Tags: git, gerrit

How can I implement Gerrit to work for some commits (require code review), and to not work (submit immediately to master branch) when I don't want code review?
Is setting like this possible?

P.S. work with Gerrit and Git "server", not Github.

Comment: Push to `origin refs/heads/your-branch` bypasses review entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- commits with review go to `origin refs/for/[your-branch]`
- commits without review go to `origin [your-branch]` directly.

you may neet to configure permissions to be able to push to branches directly